# SQL: Login and Logout table and inserting logouts

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So, we have a table, lds_user_log, which logs our CSR's logins and logouts for the day.  This is fine, and I have a script that is designed to pull their minutes logged in per day for our metrics:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpLogins1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpLogins1
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpLogins') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpLogins


SELECT  T1.[user], 
        T1.[user_group], 
        T1.event_Date, 
        isnull( MIN(T2.event_date),'2018-05-21 17:00:0') AS Date2, 
        DATEDIFF(minute, T1.event_Date,  isnull( MIN(T2.event_date),'2018-05-21 17:00:0')) AS minDiff

INTO #tmpLogins1

FROM    [LEADS].[dbo].[lds_User_log] T1
        LEFT JOIN [LEADS].[dbo].[lds_User_log] T2
            ON T1.[user_group]= T2.[user_group]
            AND T2.event_Date > T1.event_Date
            and t1.[user]=t2.[user]
            where t1.event_date>= @startdate
            --AND t2.event_date <= '2018-05-21 23:00:01'

GROUP BY T1.[user], T1.[user_group], T1.event_Date; 



select distinct [user],
user_group,
sum(minDiff) over (partition by [user]) as totMins
 INTO #tmpLogins
 from #tmpLogins1
```

This returns:

[image: Results 1]

Which again is fine, but some of our CSRs do not log out of their system, which leaves a NULL in the LOGOUT event, where (because I don't know another way of doing it) forces me to use the ISNULL from above, assuming they left at 5 PM.

Is there a way that, even using temp tables, I can take a user who has a LOGIN but not a LOGOUT for the same day, and force that into the LOGOUT temp table? This is because we want to be able to run this report for an entire week, and some reps will go home and never log out (by just closing their browser) and then logging back in the next day, never generating a LOGOUT event.  But we need it as

```
FRI - 1st LOGIN |  LAST LOGOUT
MON - 1st LOGIN |  LAST LOGOUT
TUE - 1st LOGIN |  LAST LOGOUT
WED - 1st LOGIN |  LAST LOGOUT
THU - 1st LOGIN |  LAST LOGOUT
```

and the MINUTES between each of those, and again, assuming they left at 5 PM (1700) that specific day IF they did not generate a LOGOUT event.

When I do a pull on all the data from the table for a specific user for yesterday.

```
select * 
from LEADS.[dbo].[lds_User_log]
where [USER] = 'gunnr' AND event_date > '2018-05-21 00:00:01'
```

It does list :

[image: Results 2]

And here's the entire field list:

```
SELECT [user_log_id]
      ,[user]
      ,[event]
      ,[campaign_id]
      ,[event_date]
      ,[event_epoch]
      ,[user_group]
      ,[session_id]
      ,[server_ip]
      ,[extension]
      ,[computer_ip]
      ,[browser]
      ,[data]
      ,[phone_login]
      ,[server_phone]
      ,[phone_ip]
      ,[webserver]
      ,[login_url]
      ,[browser_width]
      ,[browser_height]
  FROM [LEADS].[dbo].[lds_User_log]
```

Comment: Can they ever logout in the middle of the day?  Giving : `In @ 9am, Out @ 12pm, In @ 1pm, Out @ NULL`?  *(Even if infrequent, it would still need dealing with...)*  Or, if they log in at 9am, close their browser at 12pm, log in again at 1pm, close their browser at 5pm, how can you tell the 1pm even was a login and not a logout?

Comment: How can they log back in the next day if they never logged out? Can the same user be logged in twice? Can you set a timeout for inactivity in the app/environment?

Comment: Create a job that runs at the end of the day that autologs people out that have a login of that day at have not logged out - this will also force them to relog back in the next day giving you better data

Comment: @MatBailie - Yes they can, they are infact supposed to - LOGIN at 8:30 AM, LOGOUT at 1200, LOGIN at 1230, LOGOUT at 1700.

Comment: @dfundako Becasue our system is REAL ODD.... not something really I can influence.

Comment: @DanielMarcus - I sadly cannot, and IT proper will not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  [user_group],
  [user],
  pivots.event_date,
  MIN(pivots.login)             AS first_login,
  CASE
    WHEN MAX(pivots.login) < MAX(pivots.logout)
      THEN MAX(pivots.logout)
      ELSE DATEADD(HOUR, 17, pivots.event_date)
  END
                               AS last_logout
FROM
  [LEADS].[dbo].[lds_User_log]
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT CAST(CAST(event_date AS DATE) AS DATETIME)       AS event_date,
         CASE WHEN event = 'LOGIN'  THEN event_date END   AS login,
         CASE WHEN event = 'LOGOUT' THEN event_date END   AS logout
)
  pivots
GROUP BY
  [user_group],
  [user],
  pivots.event_date
```

Or, more flexibly...

```
WITH
  augmented
AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY event_date_only,
                                    [user_group],
                                    [user]
                           ORDER BY event_date DESC
                      )
                        AS reverse_seq
  FROM
    [LEADS].[dbo].[lds_User_log]
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT CAST(CAST(event_date AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
  )
    AS date_only(event_date_only)
)
SELECT
    [user_group],
    [user],
    event_date_only,
    MIN(login)             AS first_login,
    MAX(logout)            AS last_logout
FROM
  augmented
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN event = 'LOGIN'  THEN event_date END   AS login,
           CASE WHEN event = 'LOGOUT' THEN event_date END   AS logout

    UNION ALL

    -- Creates a "fake" logout if the last event of the day is a login
    SELECT NULL,
           DATEADD(HOUR, 17, event_date_only)
     WHERE reverse_seq = 1
       AND event = 'LOGIN'
)
  AS pivots
GROUP BY
  [user_group],
  [user],
  event_date_only
```

Comment: I apologize, I'll update, there are [event] which indicated logins and logouts.  I'll update the main post for it.

Comment: Also, I got : Msg 9810, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.

Comment: @dragos_kai : Do you want the total time between first login and last logout, or the accumulated logout - preceding_login *(8:30 to 12:00 plus 12:30 to 17:00 being 8 hours, or 8.5 hours?)*

Comment: @dragos_kai : If the first event in a day is a logout, how do you want that handled?

Comment: The accumulated time between the earliest LOGIN event and the latest LOGOUT event (or 1700 if there is no LOGOUT on the day) Also, I don't think it's physically possible for them to have it be a LOGOUT as their first action.  I have reviewed this, and it hasn't been a thing (at least for 3 years, the latest I have access to.

Comment: @dragos_kai : So, of the two options I gave, you want 8.5 hours?

Comment: @dragos_kai : What if the last event of a day is a login, and that login is ***after*** 17:00?

Comment: Yeah, the 8.5 hours is fine.  Though, just as a head's up, I need to report on **minutes** not hours, I handle the hours conversion later in the report.  

Also, every rep leaves at 17:00, so there won't be a login after 1700.  The only people who are here after 1700 are people like me who don't log into that CMS.

Comment: That works out well, is there any way to do the DATEDIFF(m) on the first_login and last_logout?

Though, thank you so much for this.

Comment: @dragos_kai : Just wrap the whole thing in another query and do `DATEDIFF(minute, first_login, last_logout)`?

Comment: Where would you put the semicolon in this to insert it into a temp table? I can't get it to work anywhere in SSMS

Comment: At the very very end.  WITH () INSERT INTO target SELECT FROM WHERE GROUP BY HAVING ORDER BY;